# Trigger with "NEW" doesn't work

Tags: mysql

it's the first time for me with triggers on MySQL.

I've two different tables ('users' and 'prova') and I want to insert a new row in 'prova' every time there is a new row in the 'users' table.

> CREATE TRIGGER `inserisciemail`
>       AFTER INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
>       BEGIN
>           INSERT INTO prova (provaemail)
>           VALUES (NEW.email);
>       END

The field 'provaemail' results empty and only the id field is filled (autoincremented).
What's wrong?

Vito

Comment: it should work. Can you please share your table schemas and the INSERT statement for 'users' table? Are you sure `users`.`email` is not empty?

Comment: ok, the problem is the @ symbol. If I use another "simple" field it goes OK ... argh!

Comment: @ symbol? I do not think it should be an issue. What is the problem with it? Do you see any errors?

Comment: no error. Just an empty field. But if I use the trigger for the username field (rather then the email one) it's all ok.

Comment: I repeat my earlier question - Are you confirm that the email field has a value and is not empty?

Comment: hmm! can you share the table structures for "users" and "prova" and the INSERT statement on "users" table?

Comment: thank's Abhay here http://pastie.org/3166258 the sql code

Answer (score 1):

I'm moving our discussion here because SO suggests to avoid extended discussions in comments.

So, thank you for the SQLs but I'm afraid they didn't include the CREATE TABLE for "prova" and the INSERT statement running on "users" table.

Anyways, I created the "users" table and the trigger on my dev environment. Then I created my own version of "prova" table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `prova` (
 `provaemail` VARCHAR(40)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then ran the below insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `email`) VALUES (1, 'guptaabhay@gmail.com');
```

And a new entry was inserted to "prova", here:

```
mysql> select * from prova;
+----------------------+
| provaemail           |
+----------------------+
| guptaabhay@gmail.com |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So the trigger worked!

It would be great if you could share the schema for "prova" and your `INSERT INTO users` query so that we can research further. I'm sure something's amiss.

**EDIT 1**

Thank you for the INSERTs. They ran fine and the "prova" table has now the following entries:

```
mysql> select * from prova;
+-----------------------+
| provaemail            |
+-----------------------+
| genoveffa@dominio.it  |
| peto@dominio.it       |
| test@dominio.it       |
| gianni@dominio.it     |
| nuovissimo@dominio.it |
| new@dominio.it        |
| vit@dominio.it        |
+-----------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So nothing weird till now! Why don't you try these steps once at your end:

1. create "users" table
2. create trigger
3. create "prova" table (using the CREATE statement I've given above)
4. fire the inserts as given on http://pastie.org/3166828
5. do `SELECT * FROM prova;`

And let me know whatever you see?

Comment: please refer to EDIT 1 in the response

Comment: Thank's, I tryed also. It's all fine. The problem it's only when a new row it's created by SQLAlchemy(+Plone) ... argh!

Comment: SQLAlchemy and Plone are new to me and I can't really suggest if they should be breaking your code. But if you're running the MySQL engine, I believe the query should run fine notwithstanding from where it is run